# How do I find the probability involving the normal distribution function for $P(X \le 16.50)$?

Tags: probability, integration, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, normal-distribution

Given the distribution
$$\frac{1}{1.01\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{x - 19.47}{1.01}\right)^2},$$
how do I find the probability involving the normal distribution for $P(X \le 16.50)$?

I want to find it using integration and I know there's something to do with the Maclurin or Taylor series.

Comment: Look up a table of normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Here $\sigma=1.01$, $\mu=19.47$, s.t., we have

$P(X\leq 16.50)$

$= \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{16.50}e^{-\frac{{(x-\mu)^2}}{2\sigma^2}}dx$

$= \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{(16.50-19.47)/1.01}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\sigma dz$, substitute $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$, s.t., $dx=\sigma dz$

$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{-2.940594}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz$

$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-2.940594}^{0}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz$

$= \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-2.940594}^{0}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz$, being standard normal pdf symmetric around $z=0$

$= \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-2.940594}^{0}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^4}{8}-\frac{z^6}{48}+\frac{z^8}{384}-\frac{z^{10}}{3840}+\ldots\right)dz$, by Maclurin

$= \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[z-\frac{z^3}{6}+\frac{z^5}{40}-\frac{z^7}{336}+\frac{z^9}{3456}-\frac{z^{11}}{42240}+\ldots\right]_{-2.940594}^{0}$, compute this sum for at least $20$ terms (the more terms you consider the better precision you get)

$=0.5-\frac{1.249209}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=0.5-0.4983623 = 0.0016377$

You can use the following `R` code to compute the sum of first $20$ terms of the series:

```
z <- -2.940594
s <- z
for (i in 1:20) {
   s <- s + (-1)^i*z^(2*i+1)/((2*i+1)*2^i*factorial(i))
}
s
# -1.249209
```

Let's verify the result by numeric integration:

```
integrate(function(z) exp(-z^2/2), lower=-Inf, upper=-2.940594)$value / sqrt(2*pi)
#[1] 0.001637919
```

and by computing the normal CDF with `pnorm()`:

```
pnorm(16.50, mean = 19.47, sd = 1.01)
#[1] 0.001637918
```

Comment: (+1) as it answers the op's question regarding usage of Maclaurin Expansion to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from going to Maclaurin Expansion of the gaussian function and then calculating(Which would both require some form of CAS) you can also use the standard normal distribution for which there are many tables,online calculators etc are available.

If $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$ ,then $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\sim N(0,1)$

If you look at the distribution you will see that the mean is $19.47$ and the standard deviation is $1.01$.

So
$\frac{X-19.47}{1.01}\sim N(0,1)$.

So $P(X\leq 16.5)=P(\frac{X-19.47}{1.01}\leq \frac{16.5-19.47}{1.01})=\\P(\frac{X-19.47}{1.01}\leq −2.94059405941)$ .

Now you use the the cdf for standard Gaussian and evaluate at $−2.94059405941$.

Or you can also use some graphing calculator like

You end up with $0.00163798590087$.

Or many books also have tables for the standard normal cdf. You can also use those.

[Here](https://www.gigacalculator.com/calculators/normal-distribution-calculator.php) is a good link for an online calculator of Standard normal cdf